# Wiring Panel for Cargo Trailer

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I have an empty cargo trailer I want to wire up for use at BBQ competitions.  Installing a 30 amp rv power inlet to be used at campgrounds or via my generator.  I will wire that to a panel.

Hooked up to the panel:

- Roof AC
- Dedicated plug for full-size fridge
- LED lights & switches
- 3 additional outlets

My question is:  Is a 60 amp 120/240 V panel the correct size to use?  Or is a 100 amp panel ok?  I keep getting conflicting answers.

Thank You

Comment: Nicely done for a first question! Please take the [tour] and browse the [help] so you can learn how to get the most out of this site

Comment: A 30 amp RV connection is usually made via the TT-30 connector, which is a 120 volt connector. If you use a 120/240 volt panel you'll have to make some accommodation - either connect both hot buses to the single incoming hot wire, or connect only one hot bus and then only install breakers in the slots served by that one bus.

Comment: How many BTU is the roof AC?

Comment: roof AC is 13,500 BTU - pulls 13.5A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it this way.  I weigh 210 pounds.  Should I buy a latter rated for 300 pounds?  Or is 225 pounds the correct ladder to use?

See, that’s one of those deals where more is always better. The goal isn’t to match safety limit to actual use, you only *need* to exceed safety margins but *it works in your favor* to exceed them by a wide margin.

### The #1 thing you need to care about is *spaces*

Spaces are the places you can put a circuit breaker.   You need one for every circuit in 120V-land, and you can’t rely on using twin/duplex/double-stuff breakers anymore due to Code changes.  So your first priority in panel selection is plenty of spaces for now and future use — including potentially converting to a 30A/240V or 50A/240V setup.  Since you’re saying travel trailer, that’s a TT30, 30A/120V.  Running 240V appliances is out, for now.

Answer (score 2):

Your panel only needs to be rated for the overcurrent protection feeding it, so it only *needs* to be rated for 30A, but you could use a 60A, 100A or even a 200A.

Comment: Thank you for that info.  I was going to install a 100A due to easily purchased at local hardware store (60A harder to find), just want to make sure breakers will trip when supposed to if overloaded.

Comment: Breakers will trip at their rating regardless of panel rating.

Comment: Yes. You can always go larger on the panel than the feed, but not smaller.  The over-current protection would be where you plug in at the competition site and your feed cable needs to be sized to handle that.  +